# oauth2-proxy not working with AWS Network Load Balancer on kubernetes(KOPS)

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, nginx-ingress, amazon-elb, kops

Initially, I deployed Oauth2 single sign-on proxy(using GCP APIs and services) on my Kubernetes cluster(using KOPS) with an ingress-nginx-controller provisioned with a classic load balancer. The Oauth2 proxy works fine using the following annotations on the ingress resources:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://$host/oauth2/auth
```

Controller pod log shows 200 status and resources load fine on the web browser:

```
172.26.2.112 - - [11/Apr/2022:09:03:13 +0000] "GET /assets/images/resources/sa.svg HTTP/2.0" 200 535 "https://argocd.infra.example.com/applications/oauth2-proxy?resource=" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36" 52 0.015 [argocd-argocd-server-443] [] 100.105.130.90:8080 535 0.016 200 8891ecb604a8db0edda63e184535793b
172.26.2.112 - - [11/Apr/2022:09:03:13 +0000] "GET /assets/images/resources/ing.svg HTTP/2.0" 200 369 "https://argocd.infra.example.com/applications/oauth2-proxy?resource=" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36" 53 0.007 [argocd-argocd-server-443] [] 100.105.130.90:8080 369 0.008 200 4214b05d5b2cbadae0ae04b0f3393b21
```

But based on my team's requirement, I had to change my Ingress-Nginx-Controller provisioning AWS Network Load balancer instead of the default Classic Load Balancer and I did that now. I could expose all my apps service through NLB provisioned by KOPs.

But the issue now I am facing is the Oauth2 proxy or its annotations on ingress resources stopped working. Following are the logs with HTTP code 499 when using Oauth2 proxy with NLB controller.

```
100.115.172.192 - - [11/Apr/2022:09:00:00 +0000] "GET /oauth2/auth HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36" 2729 49.817 [argocd-argocd-server-443] [] - - - - 6efc0c5ade6cdfefd2e275f366bdcfd5
100.115.172.192 - - [11/Apr/2022:09:00:00 +0000] "GET /oauth2/auth HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36" 2729 49.809 [argocd-argocd-server-443] [] - - - - 6efc0c5ade6cdfefd2e275f366bdcfd5
172.26.2.112 - - [11/Apr/2022:09:00:00 +0000] "GET /oauth2/auth HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36" 2729 49.797 [argocd-argocd-server-443] [] - - - - 6efc0c5ade6cdfefd2e275f366bdcfd5
```

Is it because the controller load balancer changed from Classic(Layer 7) to Network Load Balancer(Layer 4) and the Oauth2 proxy simply cannot work or understand the requesting header this way?.

I could not find a workaround yet to have Oauth2 proxy working with NLB.

Answer (score 0):

you might need this:

```
access_by_lua_block {
    ngx.var.pass_access_scheme = "https"
    ngx.var.pass_port = "443"
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on where exactly to add this?.

Comment: NLB will remove the https related header, like scheme, port. here it adds back.

Comment: thank you but what I am asking is, where need to add this header you provided above? on the particular ingress resource of the specific service?

Comment: here is an example: https://gist.github.com/weiyuDatawiza/86e1bd15808a5e968bc37aa64c172f36. But we did not use oauth2-proxy. We make it work for NLB + ingress-nginx + our product. Our product is an alternative to oauth2-proxy.